# MEAN stack app do not load images while accessing from another device than localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I'm building a Book sharing site for practicing MEAN stack as I'm new to it.

Everything works pretty fine in my local development environment in localhost. It retrieves posts, images and everything. Then I tried to access the site from other devices by hosting the site with my LAN IP with the command for Angular `ng serve --host 192.168.0.107` and for Node `npm run start:server --host 192.168.0.107`.

But the problem is, when I access it from another laptop and mobile which are in the same LAN, the site loads all posts pretty fine, except the images.

This is what it looks in my PC in which I developed it which runs a **Ubuntu 16.04** OS.

[image]

When I access it from my **Windows 7** PC it looks like,

[image]

And when I access from my Android device it looks like this,

[image]

All the images are missing.

Here is the code where I have set the CORS Headers.

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, PUT, OPTION");
  next();
});
```

From other devices that I'm trying to access there in console it shows `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I have been searching for hours for similar questions, none of them matched my situation. Even the slightest clue would mean great help.

Comment: What does the browser console say? 404 errors for the images, 500, …?

Comment: Thank you for response sir. It shows `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. But I'm not getting how can I make the resources available for other devices.

Comment: You’re serving both HTML code and images from the same origin though, right? Can you show an example of how exactly you’re referring the images in the HTML? Do you have _anything_ configured that might be supposed to block image delivery under certain circumstances, a “hot-linking protection” or something of the sorts?

Comment: Sir, both of my Angular and Node are running on the same server with separate ports. I'm just retrieving the image path from DB through Node API and showing them in Angular component.

Comment: Could it be that you’re getting CORS errors then while trying to make that API call?

Comment: I have updated the post with my CORS headers that I have set in my **app.js** file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm at a MEAN course where I'm doing about the same thing. I assume that the images are stored in a folder on the server. For example backend/images. On the development device the access to the folder is given. To access it from another device it has to be shared.

Insert this line in app.js:

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join('backend/images'))));
```

This will share the /images folder and forward it to backend/images
It is best to insert this line before setting the headers.

I hope this helps

Comment: I have already added that, but nothing changed. Thank you for response sir.